# how to validate the fields when I click on a button at the first time?

Tags: javascript

Validation of the fields education and moral education takes place when I click on the button at the second time.

I want the validation to take place when I click on the button at the first time.

I have the following code:

```
$('body').on('change', '#education', function(){
    if( !$("#education").val() ) {
        $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');   
    }else{
        $(this).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }
});

$('body').on('change', '#moraleducation', function(){
    if( !$("#moraleducation").val() ) { 
        $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    }else{
        $(this).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }
});

//education
$('body').on('click', '#update', function(){
    if($("body #education").hasClass('parsley-error')){
        $("body #education").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    }  
});

//moraleducation
$('body').on('click', '#update', function(){
    if($("#moraleducation").hasClass('parsley-error')){
        $("#moraleducation").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    }   
});
```

Comment: I think you have to be more specific, you're adding a class, and adding the same class again probably makes no difference? Maybe you wanted to remove the class instead

Comment: And when you are adding class parsley-error to #education

Answer (score 0):

Console log the on-click, see if there's an error on first click. What does the rest of your code look like? Could be the order you're placing the functions in.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tag a wild guess, and say you probably wanted this

```
$(document).on('click', '#update', function() {
    var edu_err = $('#education').hasClass('parsley-error');
    var mor_err = $('#moraleducation').hasClass('parsley-error');

    $('#education').closest('.form-group').toggleClass('has-error', !edu_err);
    $('#moraleducation').closest('.form-group').toggleClass('has-error', !mor_err);
});
```

Where you toggle the error class, based on the descendants error class etc.

Comment: hey adeneo..your code works..but there is a problem.validation takes place when i click on the update button on the second time.i want to validate it when i click on the button on the first time

Comment: I'm guessing that's just the flags, try it now with the flags swapped

Comment: i can't understand adeneo..will upls help me to swap flgs